# Azure Data Factory: For each item() value does not exist for a particular attribute

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a for each activity which has a stored procedure (SP) wherein I am inputing values using item() evidently.

Now suppose SP's input values are item().a, item().b and item().c

Question: For some of the iteration of foreach, item().b does not exist which is expected. So how should i deal with it in the Stored procedure? Because at this point of time it is giving me an error when it executed SP by saying:

> "The template language expression 'item().b' cannot be evaluated because property 'b' doesn't
>   exist, available properties are 'a, c'

or how should I overcome this failure in the data factory?

Apparently, data factory has the check for empty() but it does not have the check for exist().

Comment: In your foreach, for those not exists value, could you give it a null? And in your stored procedures, handle that null value. Another thing, maybe you could try “?”. I.e.,  item()?.b

Comment: I can handle Null in SP but the problem is, web actitivity or REST response is the input of foreach, hence i am sure i can't edit it. However, can you please explain what does ? do after item()?

Comment: This is the doc for question mark. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#operators

Comment: And this is a related thread about question mark. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c6af1ac9-6c5f-48b8-816e-3294e62c288d/what-does-question-mark-mean?forum=azurelogicapps

Comment: I am sorry it did work. I mistakenly forgot to add @ before item() hence it took it as a text. I am going to delete my previous comment to not mis-lead the people. Thanks @FangLiu Can you please post it as a comment and I will accept the answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use “?”. I.e., item()?.b

Please reference [question mark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#operators) and a related [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c6af1ac9-6c5f-48b8-816e-3294e62c288d/what-does-question-mark-mean?forum=azurelogicapps).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can solve this in the Data Factory. You could use the String(Item()) to convert it to a Json string in the format:

```
{
    'a':'value',
    'b':'value',
    'c':'value'
}
```

Then you can handle that in your stored procedure with some creative SQL:

```
DECLARE @jsonParams NVARCHAR(255) = '
    {
        "a":"a value",
        "c":"b value"
    }' 


DECLARE @paramA VARCHAR(10) = (SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonParams,'$.a'))
DECLARE @paramB VARCHAR(10) = (SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonParams,'$.b'))
DECLARE @paramC VARCHAR(10) = (SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonParams,'$.c'))
```

Comment: So what happens to the 'b' tag which did not exist in the input? I know item() is a dict and i can convert it into json but your example just converting a dict to a json and inputting it to a SP. I am not sure how does that solve my problem.

Comment: Fang Liu's answer is better. My idea was passing the whole json object into the stored procedure and handle the abscence of 'b' there. My example code will give null and not throw an error.