# Check Stored procedure has retured a value

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am a newbie to Datafctory. As part of my pipeline, I execute an sp to fetch the next record to process using Lookup and then use the returned value in a Set Variable.

If the SP returns noting then the Set Variable fails with the following error

Activity SetBatchId failed: The expression 'activity('usp_get_next_archive_batch').output.firstRow.id' cannot be evaluated because property 'firstRow' doesn't exist, available properties are 'effectiveIntegrationRuntime'.

Is there a way in DF to check the property exists before using it

thanks

Comment: Not a pro "yet" but i think you can add a "if condition" to your pipeline 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity

Comment: If the SP returns no value then firstRow property will not be present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add a question mark after ‘output’. Means ‘output?.firstRow’.

See also this post. 
[Azure Data Factory: For each item() value does not exist for a particular attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222698/azure-data-factory-for-each-item-value-does-not-exist-for-a-particular-attrib?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The expression should be 'activity('usp_get_next_archive_batch').output['firstRow'].['id']