# How can I check if a JSON field exists using an ADF expression?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to do some activity in an ADF pipeline, but only if a field in a JSON output is present. What kind of ADF expression can I use to check that?

Comment: Some sample data and expected results please?

Comment: One way to check that is explained here, https://endjin.com/blog/2021/02/how-to-safely-reference-a-nullable-activity-output-in-synapse-pipelines-and-azure-data-factory

Comment: Looks like a nice technique, ?subtle though!

Comment: I was able to create two json files, one with a firstName attribute, one without.  I can then use a Lookup to load the files, and check if the attribute exists in a Set Variable activity using the following expression:  `@bool(contains(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow, 'firstName'))`.  I was able to use that boolean variable in an If condition.   I can work up screenprints etc if that sounds like it would work for you.

Comment: @wBob, Yes why not. You can then put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set up two json files for testing, one with a firstName attribute and one without:

[image: test json files]

I then created a [Lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to get the contents of the JSON file and a [Set Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) activity for testing the expression.  I often use these to test expressions and it's a good way to test and view expression results iteratively:

[image: Synapse pipeline]

I then created a Boolean variable (which is one of the datatypes supported by Azure Data Factory and Synapse pipelines) and the expression I am using to check the existence of the attribute is this:

```
@bool(contains(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow, 'firstName'))
```

You can then use that boolean variable in an [If activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity), to execute subsequent activities conditionally based on the value of the variable.

Comment: Is there a way to check if firstRow exits? Ran into similar problem, but rather than looking for value looki ng for firstRow

Comment: Try changing it to just output instead of output.firstRow, but I can’t check as I’m out this week.

Comment: Thanks!, it doesnot work, but this solution helped me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222698/azure-data-factory-for-each-item-value-does-not-exist-for-a-particular-attrib?rq=1